# SSH: Windows : Git/Gerrit : No matching key exchange method found - Their offer diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gerrit, openssh

I have my Git/Gerrit set up on my Ubuntu PC and the below worked fine.   However, I am trying to do the same on my Windows PC, but it fails to clone the repository saying - 
*"Unable to negotiate with 55.115.127.145 port 9418: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository."*

Adding below in ~/.ssh/config: doesn't work too !

```
Host your_email@lab126.com
              KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host 55.115.127.145
    HostName 55.115.127.145
    User <myname>
    Port 9418 
                  KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**Below are the detailed steps I followed:**
1) Downloaded and installed Git from http://git-scm.com/downloads
2) **Setup Your Git Username and Email**

```
git config --global user.name "FirstName LastName"
git config --global user.email "your_email@lab126.com"
```

3) **Set up RSA key**
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@lab126.com
   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   Enter file in which to save the key **(/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa):** 
   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
4) Public Private keys saved in **(/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa)** and (/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) files
5)  **Set Up Gerrit :** 
    Login to https://e-gerrit.lab.net/
6) In Gerrit, Select settings -> SSH Public Keys -> Add Key -> Copy & Paste Public Key
7) Open cmd line and clone the repository

```
C:\Git>git clone ssh://e-gerrit.lab.net:9418/framework -b test
```

8) Add config file in ~/.ssh/ as above

Comment: i think it doesn't like 55.115.127.145

Comment: Try replacing 55.115.127.145 with https://e-gerrit.lab.net/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Ritesh!! It works !!